# How to Track my sites URLs across the web? Not using google analytics

Tags: url, tracking

Sorry for the simple question but I've searched through the forums for 2 hours.

Goal:

I want to track my websites URLs across the web. I'm current using google analytical to do tracking which is fine for me. But I want to show my users where their links are being clicked when they login to their account.

What's the best way I can do this? I'm using a php backed if that helps. My goal is to provide: how many times their links are clicked and where the URL was clicked from.

Comment: analytics has an API to allow you to query and extract data - is that not suitable?  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/

Comment: Is this how Hootsuite or other sites report analytical to end users? I'd prefer to learn how to do it before relying on google. Any help would be Appeciated.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I was hoping somebody else would give you a better hint, but since the question doesn't seem to attract many people I'll try to give you a better answer.

So, breaking down your problem to pieces, you want to trigger a piece of code everytime a page is accessed. You should be able to do a mapping between the page and its owner at one point - when rendering the statistics. If you want to "cut corners" and have a simple solution, you simply insert into your database a new entry describing the event. You seem to be only interested in the number of times it was accessed, so for a specific `pageID`, you can `count` how many entries there is, so this data can be computed directly from your database.

Now, the interesting part, figuring out where the visitor comes from. If you take a look at the `$_SERVER` variable for PHP, documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), you will see that it contains a lot of interesting information. I think you're mostly interested in `'HTTP_REFERER'` which contains

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the
>   current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will
>   set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a
>   feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Looking quickly on Stack Overflow I didn't find a more trustable source, so when available, I guess that's the only data you can use.

If you want to make things a bit more robust, you could log the `IP address` of the visitor and only count `1` visit per day.

So, to recapitulate, you create a table which logs the visits, containing the `pageID` and `referer` (optionally the `IP address` and `date` to prevent multiple insertions on the same day from the same user if you want to be strict). You add a function call to each page that will record the information of your `pageID`, maybe the URL or an ID you use internally? and the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. Then, when a user wants to see his stats, you look up every `pageID` that belongs to him, then pull the `count` of entries for that page and all the referers.

I hope my explanations are clear. It's definitely not bulletproof, but it's simple and should do the job, and it can be programmed pretty quickly.

Old answer: Piwik (documented [here](http://piwik.org/)) is pretty similar to Google Analytics. Since you own the database where the data is stored, you could probably extract all the data you want, the way you want it, and manipulate it the way you want without having to depend on someone else (Google).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I think this might be overkill for what I'm trying to do. I just want to tell my users two things: number of URLs they have on other sites and what sites those URLs are located on. Is there a easy way to track this?

Comment: I'm not sure about an easy way to do that, sorry